# Как подключить данные в Highchart и отрендерить в React

Tags: reactjs, диаграммы, highcharts

У меня есть отдельный файл с данными data.tsx, я так понимаю, что его нельзя подключить к нативному js, если это так, то как его отредактировать? Но главный вопрос у другом, как мне подключить этот файл к своему react-приложению и используя эти данные построить подобный график (см. ниже) с использованием Highchart?

[Проект полностью на Github](https://github.com/carboncheg/report_with_chart)

*data.tsx (сокращённая версия)*

```
export interface DataRow {
    name: string,
    feature1: number,
    feature2: number,
    year: number
}

const products: DataRow[] = [
    { name: "Product 0", feature1: 30, feature2: 51.6, year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 1", feature1: 167.5, feature2: 59, year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 2", feature1: 159.5, feature2: 49.2, year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 3", feature1: 157, feature2: 63, year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 4", feature1: 155.8, feature2: 53.6, year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 0", feature1: 166.8, feature2: 56.6, year: 2016 },
    { name: "Product 1", feature1: 172.7, feature2: 105.2, year: 2016 },
    { name: "Product 2", feature1: 163.5, feature2: 51.8, year: 2016 },
    { name: "Product 3", feature1: 169.4, feature2: 63.4, year: 2016 },
    { name: "Product 4", feature1: 167.8, feature2: 59, year: 2016 },
];

export default products;
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import DataRow from './data.tsx';

const options = {
    chart: {
        type: "scatter"
    },
    title: {
        text: "Goods"
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: [1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 3]
        }
    ]
};

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts = {Highcharts} options = {options} />
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

[image: Scatter_chart]

Answer (score 0):

Вся информация есть в [документации](https://www.highcharts.com) (она у них хорошая).

Привожу пример подключения точек. Вам же предварительно нужно выбрать необходимую инфу разделив ее на оси X и Y.

```
const options = {
    chart: {
        type: "scatter"
    },
    title: {
        text: "Goods"
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Feature 2'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Feature 1'
        }
    },

    series: DataRow,
};
```

Если не будет получаться - напишите в ЛС покажу похожий рабочий пример.